# C++ char getting errors?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, pointers

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char[] name = { "Nitish prajapati" }; 
    char* namePointer = &name ;

    std::cout << "\n name    = " << name;
    std::cout << "\n &name    = " << &name;
    std::cout << "\n &namePointer    = " << &namePointer;
    std::cout << "\n namePointer    = " << namePointer;

    return 0;
}
```

Why does this program give the error : `expected unqualified-id before '[' token`?
        and
 explain how you actually use char along with reference and dereference (i.e pointer)

Comment: `char name[]` ! not `char[] name`

Comment: char[] name ?? this is not c++

Comment: Ok cool!! I feel stupid now :) thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These both statements are wrong

```
char[] name = { "Nitish prajapati" }; 
char* namePointer = &name ;
```

In C++ valid declaration of an array looks like

```
char name[] = { "Nitish prajapati" };
```

As for the second statement then there is no implicit conversion from type `char ( * )[17]` to `char *`.
The initializer of the declaration has type `char ( * )[17]` while declared pointer has type `char *`

You should write either

```
char* namePointer = name ;
```

or

```
char ( *namePointer)[17] = &name ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
const char name[] = {"Nitish prajapati"}; 
const char* namePointer = name ;
```

Comment: Doesn't necessarily need to be `const` (and if it were, the pointer would need changing too).

Comment: There's no reason for the array to be `const`.